# Hyperledger Fabric Application Architecture

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm very confused on the architecture of hyperledger fabric application I should create.

After chaincode is installed on peer in the network, user can query or invoke the smart contract using Hyperledger Fabric SDK.

My question is, which implementation is better in practice?

Setup web/mobile application which user can directly interact with the blockchain network (ONE layer).

OR

Setup API server application (backend) and web/mobile application (frontend), backend will act as intermediate between the blockchain and client in the frontend and process client's request into query/invoke operation to the blockchain network. (TWO layers)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'd be able to use the Fabric SDK directly on mobile, so I think your second approach would be better.

If you were to create an API server, in theory you could create several web applications and mobile applications which make simple REST calls.
Also, if you were to create an API server, technically you'd be able to scale it up if required.